# Magento 1.9.3.4 All report pages missing in navigation dropdown

Tags: magento-1.9, reports

I can't view any reports in this Magento Backend:

[image]

Reports are activated in the System Configuration but the only report in the reports dropdown is "Paypal Settlement reports".

Any ideas what is happening here? I have absolutely no idea.

Comment: Are you login with administrator super user ? If no then login with super user and check the user permission in system configuration

Comment: @PurushotamSharma yes, i'm logged in as super user :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that there is a difference between `System > Configuration > GENERAL > Reports > General > Enable Reports` and `System > Configuration > ADVANCED > Advanced > Disable Module Output > Mage_Reports`.

The described symptoms would match onto the `Mage_Reports` output being disabled (in a default setup, when Mage_Reports is disabled, only `Reports > Sales > PayPal Settlement Reports` and `Reports > Tags > Customers / Products / Popular`).

Comment: you're welcome, glad I was able to help